# Audio spells markup when ssml format passed in Ivona

Tags: text-to-speech, ssml

when i call Ivona API with input as ssml format, i get audio which pronounce ssml markup.

How to correctly call using ssml as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reqesting the audio with request type as 'text/plain'. The correct input type will be 'application/ssml+xml'.

I am using ivona-node library to get the audio.

The format will be something like this:

```
var audioText = '<?xml version="1.0"?><speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US"><p><s>This is the first sentence of the paragraph.</s><s>Here is another sentence.</s></p></speak>';

ivona.createVoice(audioText, {
  body: {
    input: {
      data: null,
      type: 'application/ssml+xml'
    },
    voice: {
      name: 'Raveena',
      language: 'en-IN',
      gender: 'Female'
    }
  }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.mp3'));
```